# bind_param for php pdo for select

Tags: php, pdo

i have created delete statement in php pdo. i need to know bind_param query for my code. I used one bind_param which is not wrking.

PHP7

```
public function deleteRecord($table,$pk,$id){
        if($table == "categories"){
            $pre_stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT ".$id." FROM categories WHERE parent_cat = ?");
            $pre_stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
            $pre_stmt->execute();
            $result = $pre_stmt->get_result() or die($this->con->error);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                return "DEPENDENT_CATEGORY";
            }else{
                $pre_stmt = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$pk." = ?");
                $pre_stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
                $result = $pre_stmt->execute() or die($this->con->error);
                if ($result) {
                    return "CATEGORY_DELETED";
                }
            }
```

Comment: `bind_param` is mysqli api it's `bingParam` for PDO. Same thing for `get_result() ` https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Looks like you need to read a PDO tutorial to learn the proper way to use it.

Comment: Your SELECT has `WHERE parent_cat = ?` and your DELETE has `WHERE ".$pk." = ?`

Comment: All of this is MySQLi code, and it does not make much sense. Are you sure you have posted the correct piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rectified that above and got error on below
 public function getAllRecord($table){

```
    $result = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$table);
    $result->execute();
    $results = $result->fetchAll();
    $rows = array();
    if ($results->rowCount > 0) {
        while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
    return "NO_DATA";
}
```

Error:Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\inv_project\public_html\includes\DBOperation.php on line 68